# Title of a specific stage in projects?

Tags: word-choice

In our projects we first send our clients a report with issues to fix on their website.

How to title the second stage in our projects, when we re-check the website to see if the client indeed fixed the issues in the report?

Is it: "counter-checks" - "re-check" - "repeated test" - "re-testing" -"re-evaluation check"....?

Comment: From the perspective of your team which is the most meaningful? Who sees this title?

Comment: *Verification* might apply.

Comment: in reply to "killing time" - section in  a Price Quote for clients , which describes the project workflow///

Comment: What's the title of the first stage?

Answer (score 1):

### Useful Term

**edit review** seems a good term for your described use.
First comes the check on your part, then the client edits in regards to your suggestions, your second step is the Edit Review.

As with these back-and-forth checks and edits, a multitude of reviews may occur, so you have an initial review, an undisclosed number of reviews, until you reach a final review.

Comment: Yes, REVIEW is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Who are you trying to impress here? If the stage of work you describe involves a lot of work or demands the billing of very large fees then you must use words that make the job sound as big as the fees. What words to choose is more a question of rhetoric than of grammar: you wish to evoke particular emotions on the part of your reader (ie the fee payer).

I realise that this sounds cynical but you want your client to feel that you are adding value. Your choice of words will depend on your judgement of the  words that have impact on that specific client, that speak to the client's fears of gaps in technique, that encourage the client to believe that only you can fill those gaps. You have to listen to what your client says and choose your words accordingly. It is not possible to generalise, but certain phrases come into fashion (' a systems approach' for example) and go out.

Cynical or not, none of what I say implies that you cannot add real value. My point is that you have to find a way of getting your client to **feel** that you are doing so.